# How to calculate the integral of a function with a root?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, roots

I have to solve this integral:
$\int\limits_{-1}^1(3x^3-5x^2+12x-9)~dx$

I used Grapher (a nifty program that comes with Mac OS X) to display the curve of

$f(x)=3x^3-5x^2+12x-9$

and it obviously has a root (I hope this is the right word). In the interval $[-1,1]$ most of the function is below the y axis. The function crosses the y axis somewhere close to $x=1$ but the crossing point is still in the interval.

I am a bit confused because Wolfram Alpha gives me a result of $-\dfrac{64}{3}$ ([Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20from%20-1%20to%201%20of%203x%5E3-5x%5E2%2b12x-9&lk=4&num=1)) which I can reproduce when I ignore the root.

I thought I need to calculate the root and split the interval in a part below the x axis and a part above the x axis to calculate the integral.

How to calculate an integral with roots?

Comment: When we calculate the definite (or indefinite) integral, we don't care about roots. They play no role in the calculation. But if we need $\int_a^b |f(x)|\,dx$, intervals where the function is negative do make a difference.

Comment: The first identity cannot hold since the LHS is a NUMBER while the RHS is a FUNCTION. By the way, to determine the zeroes of the function to integrate is quite unnecessary, so you might want to explain how you got the idea that it was.

Comment: @Did, I really do not know how I got the idea. I guess I mixed two related concepts. I remember a concept where the roots matter but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Did, I think I got it. There is the related concept of calculating the actual area contained (?) between a function and the x axis in a given interval.

Comment: For that particular application, you will have to integrate the absolute value. So if $f$ is non-negative from $a$ to $b$, and negative from $b$ to $c$, you will need $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx+\int_b^c -f(x)\,dx$, with the obvious adjustment if there are more intervals of negativity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all comments say, you do not need to care about roots of the function when you compute definite integrals. What you compute is the **signed** surface between the curve and the horizontal axis.

In your case, Wolfram Alpha gives a value equal to -64/3 which is correct.

The only real root of your function is at x0 = 0.906111131481595. So, I computed the value of the integral for the range [-1,x0]; the result is -21.3798 (because the curve is below the axis). I also  I computed the value of the integral for the range [x0,1]; the result is 0.046451 (because the curve is above the axis). Then the **signed** sum is -21.3798 + 0.0465 = -21.3333 which is -64/3.

Is this making your problem clearer ?

Comment: To get that exact answer, you would need an expression for the root in terms of radicals.